# Easy way to import rows into MySQL from csv file

Tags: mysql, sql, scripting, database-administration

I have a csv file that corresponds to what our user table looks like.  Essentially we need to do a bulk import, what would be a good way to do this in MySQL without writing a custom script that just issues an SQL insert?

Comment: try http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlimport.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use [load data infile](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)

IE:

```
load data local infile 'uniq.csv' into table tblUniq
fields terminated by ','
enclosed by '"'
lines terminated by '\n'
(uniqName, uniqCity, uniqComments)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use phpmyadmin

which is the best tools for developers to do every thing easyly

here you have to choose the file click csv and just lload it

very easy............right

you can download it from here

http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/downloads.php ( also install apache along with this )

you can also use wamp server which include phpmyadmin (best for windows)